# Groovy NullObject should be null or not?

Tags: reflection, groovy, null-object-pattern

This example can be easily tested in the groovy console.

var a is evaluated to not null while b is evaluated to null.

Both are instances of org.codehaus.groovy.runtim.NullObject

```
def b = null

println b.getClass()
println b == null

def a = null.getClass().newInstance()

println a.getClass()
println a == null
```

Does anyone knows why?

This is a tricky thing when dealing with reflection code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am wondering if this is not a bug. As an explanation... NullObject is a runtime/intermediate kind of Object. If you do anything on null, then NullObject is used. This, and the the implementation of NullObject#equals speaks for a==null returning true. It returns fails, because there is some internal code before that, that is for example determining if compareTo is called instead of equals and such things. Now this piece of code starts with

```
if (left == right) return true; 
if (left == null || right == null) return false;
```

so null==null will return true, but NullObject==null will return false. On the other hand NullObject should not leak out if possible. Maybe we should fix newInstance() to return null.

I filled [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5769](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507205309/https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5769) for this

Answer (score 0):

In the equals method of NullObject, it only returns `true` if [you are comparing it](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/NullObject.java#L80) to `null`

As an instance of `NullObject` is not strictly `null`, it returns false...

Whether `NullObject` should return `true` if you call `equals` against another `NullObject` is probably a question best asked on the mailing list...  I'll have a look and see if I can find any previous question.

Comment: But in this case both objects are NullObjects, right? Or "b" is strictly null and the b.getClass() is obfuscating it?

Comment: Yeah, both objects are `NullObject`.  `NullObject.equals` *specifically* (see link above) checks `to == null` and this evaluates to `false` as `NullObject != null` in the Java implementation....  Not sure I'm explaining very well...

Comment: I can't see why. In both cases there will be "to == null" with the "to" object as an NullObject.

Comment: Yeah, and in Java (which NullObject is written in), only `null == null`...  `NullObject != null`